# Given a space, is there a notion of "how many" open sets contain a given point?

Tags: general-topology, measure-theory

Say $(X,\tau)$ is a topological space and pick some point $x\in X$.  Define $U_x := \{U\in \tau \;|\; x \in U \}$.  Is there a way to put a measure on $\tau$ so that we can meaningfully compare the number of open sets containing a point $x$ to the number of open sets containing a point $y$?

My motivation for this question is as follows: given two points $x$, $y \in X$, I want to use such a measure (if it exists) to describe the "distance" between $x$ and $y$ in purely topological terms.  It seems to me that if there is an open set containing both $x$ and $y$ then this means $x$ and $y$ are "close" to each with respect to some locality scale, and if I could find out how much of the space's topology belongs to the subcollection $U_{xy}:=U_x \cap U_y$ then my thought is that I would have information pertaining to how "close" $x$ and $y$ are taking into account all locality scales.  Is this idea a meaningful one and, if so, where can I go to learn more about how it works?  If it is not meaningful, why not?

Comment: Why is measure theory relevant to the question?

Comment: @Ahmed I don't know that it is. I am a novice in measure theory, but my thought was that a path to finding the answer might involve finding a measure on collections like the ones I described.

Comment: I think this is an interesting idea, but your measure may or may not work out. If the idea is to describe the distance in terms of the number of open sets containing a pair, note that in the plane, more open sets contain points that are closer together, since you can also include the smaller open sets, in addition to the big disks.

Comment: @Alfred You're right, I suppose it's more a similarity measure than a distance measure.

Comment: There will always be an open set contsining both $x$ and $y$: $X$. Additionally, $U_{xy}= \{ A \cup B|A \in U_x, B \in U_y \}$.

Comment: There already is a notion of a space endowed with a structure such that you can "compare" some sort of "distance" between points, without attaching a number to it, namely the notion of a uniform space.
A uniform space is on some sense the most general setting where you can make statements like:
"Point $A$ is as far away from point $B$, as point $C$ is to point $D$".
You can then show that a topological space is uniformizable iff it is $T_{3\frac{1}{2}}$ (not necessarily Hausdorff).
So it's hard for me to imagine, that your idea will work in an arbitrary topological space.

Comment: Far more significant is the least cardinality of a neighborhood basis at the point. See "character ... at a point" [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cardinal_function#Cardinal_functions_in_topology). For other web pages, [this google search](https://www.google.com/search?q=topology+%22character%22+%22cardinal+function%22+%22point%22) looks useful.

Comment: This might work with some spaces. But with many commonly-studied spaces, $ U_x,U_y,$ and $U_x\cap U_y$ always have the same infinite cardinality.

Comment: @DanielWainfleet But what I'm talking about is assigning a measure to $\tau$ so that $U_x$, $U_y$, and $U_{xy}$ may have different measures even though they have the same cardinalities.

Answer (score 1):

Sure, why not?  You could let $O_x$ be the cardinality of the set of open sets containing x.  I'm thinking this this cardinality should be the same for corresponding points h(x) and x under a homeomorphism h.  That is  $O_x=O_{h (x)}. $ So sort of a point wise topological invariant. ..But making this a global invariant (or what's normally meant by an invariant) appears impossible...  because different points x and y will in general have different $O_x$ and $O_y$...

Comment: I know that using cardinality does not make my idea work, and we could definitely come up with examples where $x\neq{y}\Rightarrow{U_x\neq{U_y}}$ for some $x$,$y$.  I'm talking about assigning a measure to the topology on $X$ which allows us to make distinctions between the intersections $U_x\cap{U_y}$.

Comment: Cardinality just measures the "size" of the (even infinite) set.  There are a number of invariantstudents already defined,  as in Dave L. Renfro's post,  and they all use cardinality.